# Yield in Implicitly Defined Generator?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield

In [Generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), it says

> To avoid interfering with the expected operation of the generator expression itself, yield and yield from expressions are prohibited in the implicitly defined generator

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refers to using yield expressions from within a generator expression, for example:

```
>>> g = ((yield x**2) for x in [1,2,3])                                                 
>>> list(g)                                                                             
[1, None, 4, None, 9, None]
```

Or:

```
>>> t = "hello", "world"                                                                
>>> g = ((yield from t) for x in 'xyz')                                                 
>>> list(g)                                                                             
['hello', 'world', None, 'hello', 'world', None, 'hello', 'world', None]
```

This syntax is [deprecated in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated-python-behavior) and will be a `SyntaxError` in Python 3.8+.  See [bpo10544](https://bugs.python.org/issue10544) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

It means you can't do something like:

```
sum(yield x*x for x in range(10))
```

This is apparently because the way the explicit `yield` interacts with the implicit yield in the allowed `sum(x*x for x in range(10))` would be difficult to reason about, and this would only get worse once you start using advanced techniques like `generator.send` and `generator.throw`.